# Beginner python: what's wrong with my call to check_angles? (or the method itself, if it's that)

Tags: python

My call check_angles returns the following instead of True:

```
<bound method Triangle.check_angles of <Triangle object at 0x7fb209a66b50>>
```

Here's the code:

```
class Triangle(object):
    number_of_sides = 3
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
    def check_angles():
        if angle1 + angle2 + angle3 == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False

my_triangle = Triangle(60, 60, 60)

(print my_triangle.number_of_sides)
(print my_triangle.check_angles)
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer which you find most helpful (once that option becomes available).

Comment: Conventions to name functions and variables differently exist for a reason. E.g. the good old C/Java convention to name variables using `lower_case`, methods and functions `lowerCamelCase`, classes `CapitalCamelCase`, and constants `ALL_CAPS` gives you an instant idea what is callable and what is not. Try to adopt a convention like this. (Note that PEP8's recommendations are for Python standard library; you're not bound by it in your code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses to the method call, first.

Next, you have to provide `self` as a parameter to any method in a class.

```
def check_angles(self):
```

Also, you don't want to use `angle1`, `angle2`, or `angle3` - you need to prepend those with `self.` before you can use them in the proper scope.

Finally, a style thing:  You could just return `self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180`, since it's boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `()` at the end of the method.

The output is correct: `my_triangle.check_angles` returns the function itself, so the text you get is the description of that function. To actually print the result, just do `print my_triangle.check_angles()`.

PS. Please watch out with floating point numbers. As soon as you use something other than integers, the sum may not be exactly `180`. It will be a number very close to it. If you need anything other than integers, then `abs(result-180) < 1e-6` (or some other small number to compare to) will be better.

Comment: That returns the following:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python", line 16, in <module>
    TypeError: check_angles() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: You don't have the `self` parameter in the declaration. See my answer for reference.

Comment: @user2344772 Ah - I assumed the indenting was just wrong in the question and corrected it. Please make sure you indent the methods in the class correctly - the leading whitespace in Python is very important. Have a look at the edited version of your question. (or what Sukrit said - without the original source it's hard to tell for me what's the real cause)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the parantheses to call the function.
Do.

```
class Triangle(object):
    number_of_sides = 3
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
    def check_angles(self):
        if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False

my_triangle = Triangle(60, 60, 60)

print my_triangle.number_of_sides
print my_triangle.check_angles()
```

Your implementation had slight problems, since you don't pass `self` in the function and do `self.angle1` and so on. Also, it might be useful to put the `number_of_sides` into `__init__`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I need to as self as an argument to the method AND to each of the angles in the if statement.  I somehow have been led to believe (or led myself to believe) that it would inherit self...

Comment: Just like in the `__init__` function when assigning values, you do `self.angleX`, you have to do that in every function of the class which makes use of these variables.